# Subclassing an enum value

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I want to be able to subclass some values in an enum, in order that I don't have to repeat code too much. Is there some way I can do this? Here's an example of what I want to achieve, which Eclipse quickly tells me is an abomination:

```
public enum Foo {
    BAR {
        @Override
        public void taskA() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }

        @Override
        public void taskB() {}
    },
    BAZ extends BAR {
        @Override
        public void taskB() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    };

    public abstract void taskA();
    public abstract void taskB();
}
```

`BAR` would have only the implementation of `taskA` and an empty `taskB`, and `BAZ` would have both methods - `BAR`'s implementation of `taskA`, and its own implementation of `taskB`.

I'm not changing the values of the enum after it's declared, so why doesn't this work? I could call `BAR`'s `taskA` method within `BAZ`, so why can't I do this?

Comment: @slartidan I can't, but your example below is useful to anyone else who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Enum-Constants are objects (instances), not classes. You can only subclass classes.

However even that will not work: you can only extend enums with anynomous inner classes.

You will have to find another solution for your use case. You could:

- use a static method for the shared code
- call `BAR.taskA()` in BAZ
- make taskA not abstract and put your code there
- use normal constants, instead of enums

But my favorit is:

- inject behaviour instead of overriding!

Example code:

```
class Behavior {
    public static Runnable A = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    public static Runnable B = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    public static Runnable DO_NOTHING = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        }
    }
}

public enum Foo {
    BAR(Behavior.A, Behavior.DO_NOTHING),
    BAZ(Behavior.A, Behavior.B);

    private final Runnable mechanismA;
    private final Runnable mechanismB;

    private Foo(Runnable mechanismA, Runnable mechanismB) {
        this.mechanismA = mechanismA;
        this.mechanismB = mechanismB;
    }

    public void taskA() {
        mechanismA.run;
    }

    public void taskB() {
        mechanismB.run;
    }
}
```

Pros of this solution:

- The code **explicitly** defines the behavior of each enum constant - no implicit calculations => easier to read
- You can use **inheritance**, etc in the Behavior-class
- You can easily switch behaviorA and behaviorB - or **reuse** that code anywhere else

If you have Java8 available you can even shorten the code to this:

```
public static Runnable A = () -> {
    System.out.println("A");
};
```

Comment: Actually, enum constants that override an abstract enum method (such as BAR.taskA in the question) are instances of anonymous subclasses of that enum.

Comment: It might look a bit cleaner if you use lambdas instead of Runnables (although it's already good as it is).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to subclass some values in an enum, in order that I
>   don't have to repeat code too much.

The usual way to share code among constant-specific methods is to declare a private static method (either in the enum itself or in a utility helper class) which contains the common code that you wish to access from your constant-specific methods.

For example ...

```
public enum Foo {
    BAR {
        @Override
        public void taskA() {
            commonToTaskAandB();
            System.out.println("B"); 
       }

        @Override
        public void taskB() {}
    },
    BAZ {
        @Override
        public void taskB() {
            commonToTaskAandB();
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    };

    public abstract void taskA();
    public abstract void taskB();

    private static void commonToTaskAandB() {
        // shared code here
        :
        :
    }
```

}

Note that the code "`BAZ extends Bar`" is illegal because BAZ is not a type.  BAZ is an instance of your `Enum<Foo>` type.  An instance cannot extend another type.  It is incorrect to apply object-oriented principles like inheritance to enum constants because, in Java, enum constants are instances of a class and not classes themselves.